# Window snapping bug

Tags: pantheon, window-management

Over the past couple of days I've noticed a pretty annoying bug with window snapping. I have a screen recording of the bug linked below so people can see what I'm talking about.

Basically when I snap a window to the side and release my mouse, the window will "stick" to where it was originally. At that point I'm unable to minimize the window, as seen in the video. Sometimes after I close the application the window can still be seen where it was originally.

All of these things can be seen in the screen recording. I haven't had it happen with native elementary apps, but applications like Chrome and Visual Studio Code have it happen frequently.

https://streamable.com/uoybf

Comment: I have the same problem with it. And it would relates to the windows tiling. You can see the problem as following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icrFF.gif When i dragged the edge of Terminal, another window had appended on it.
This bug really makes me mad :(